# LISTAGG inside a LISTAGG

Tags: oracle

I used some online converter to convert my view in MySQL to oracle and the result was this:

```
CREATE  VIEW actor_info
AS
SELECT
a.actor_id,
a.first_name,
a.last_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ||(c.name, ': ',
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(f.title FROM dual ORDER BY f.title SEPARATOR FROM dual ', ')
                    FROM film f
                    INNER JOIN film_category fc
                      ON f.film_id = fc.film_id
                    INNER JOIN film_actor fa
                      ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
                    WHERE fc.category_id = c.category_id
                    AND fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
                 )
             )
             ORDER BY c.name SEPARATOR '; ')
AS film_info
FROM actor a
LEFT JOIN film_actor fa
  ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
LEFT JOIN film_category fc
  ON fa.film_id = fc.film_id
LEFT JOIN category c
  ON fc.category_id = c.category_id
GROUP BY a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name;
```

The converter didn't convert too well so I had to modify the query and end up with something like this:

```
    CREATE  VIEW actor_info
AS
SELECT
a.actor_id,
a.first_name,
LISTAGG(c.name || ': ',
        (SELECT LISTAGG(f.title, ', ') within group (order by f.title)
                    FROM film f
                    INNER JOIN film_category fc
                      ON f.film_id = fc.film_id
                    INNER JOIN film_actor fa
                      ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
                    WHERE fc.category_id = c.category_id
                    AND fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
                 ) 
             ) WITHIN group (order by c.name)
AS film_info
FROM actor a
LEFT JOIN film_actor fa
  ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
LEFT JOIN film_category fc
  ON fa.film_id = fc.film_id
LEFT JOIN category c
  ON fc.category_id = c.category_id
GROUP BY a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name, c.name;
```

But I'm still getting multiple errors like I can't use `distinct` in the first `listagg` or that `argument should be a constant or a function of expression in GROUP BY`. I'm out of ideas to try to solve this, any suggestions on what the error is or another way to do this view?

Comment: Some sample data and expected results would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle's `listagg()` doesn't support distinct internally, which is a bit of a pain. The other error you're getting, ORA-30497, is because you've accidneally mad ethe second `listagg()` call the delmiter for the first one.

It's a little hard to tell without sample data and expected resulsts, but it appears you're looking for something like:

```
SELECT a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name,
  LISTAGG(c.name || ': ' || (
    SELECT LISTAGG(f.title, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f.title)
    FROM film f
    INNER JOIN film_actor fa
    ON fa.film_id = f.film_id
    INNER JOIN film_category fc
    ON f.film_id = fc.film_id
    WHERE fc.category_id = c.category_id -- from main query
    AND fa.actor_id = a.actor_id -- from main query
), '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.name)
AS film_info
FROM actor a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT fa.actor_id, c.category_id, c.name
  FROM film_actor fa
  LEFT JOIN film_category fc
    ON fc.film_id = fa.film_id
  LEFT JOIN category c
  ON c.category_id = fc.category_id
) c
ON c.actor_id = a.actor_id
GROUP BY a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name;
```

The 'distinct' part is achieved with the inline view, and the inner `listagg` then only needs to find all films for that category/actor.